# PayPal IPN Return 'Note to Seller' Field

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn

When paying in PayPal, there is an option to click the 'Add' button and add a 'Note to Seller'. I have tried various variables in the IPN response but I can't find that value anywhere. I have seen that you can post the value in the 'cn' variable but can't get it back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The field you should be looking for is `memo`: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNandPDTVariables/

Comment: Tried that one and nothing comes through

Comment: @NickReeve Seems odd, did you check the IPN logs to see what is being sent?